# Identify whether the given servers time is in daylight saving or not

Tags: sql-server

I have to get local date data across many servers scattered around the globe and identify whether it is in daylight saving mode or not ?

Need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is solved in SQL Server 2016 with AT TIME ZONE. And I wrote an article about it here: http://sqlperformance.com/2016/07/sql-plan/at-time-zone

In earlier versions you'll probably need some CLR to read that information from the registry.

Comment: "sys.time_zone_info"...Just want to confirm as this is a system table right ? and it gets autorefreshed automatically every year and will have data from around the world? as i dont have sql 2016 installed as of now

Comment: It's actually a system view, which hooks into the Windows registry, so it's kept up to date via Windows, not SQL. But you query it as if it's a system table.